# Using VBA to insert hyperlink to existing string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem with inserting a link into a text string in excel.  Everything works fine except that the current workbook file path is inserted before the link for some reason.  So when I enter (in a UserForm) "www.test.com", the resulting link is "c:\path\www.test.com"  Here is my code:

```
Dim vAnchor As String
Dim vLink As String

vAnchor = Selection
vLink = TextBox2

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
vLink, TextToDisplay:=vAnchor
```

Comment: Try determining the value of `vLink` by breaking the code before setting the hyperlink. The problem may be in what you're getting back from your Text Box.

Comment: Yes, I did that with a msgbox and it returns just what I enter into the TextBox.  I found that if I leave the cell blank, a link is inserted "c:\path\currentfile.xls"  So for whatever reason, the current file is the default link.

Comment: I found that entering the address "http://test.com" works.  Apparently without the http it assumes a file and defaults to the local drive.

Comment: heh, this page assumed I wanted to put in a link.  I entered ""http://test.com""

Comment: Nice to know about the http assumption! Thanks. Didn't know that. In comments, you can use the reverse apostrophe to delimit code and keep the site from assuming links are clickable. As in: `http://test.com/`